# How do I update my global username to match my community username?

Tags: bug, profile-page, display-names

I’ve looked through the answers to this question dating from 2009-2018 and don’t find any relevant answers as I already know how to change my username on a specific community.

I am at my global profile URL: https://stackexchange.com/users/2728568

Earlier today I clicked “Update profile info” and it copied it over from a community I chose for the first time. This worked.

I decided it would be better to use an Internet handle for privacy reasons.

I went ahead and changed it on one of my communities and it asked me if I wanted to copy this information across all communities. I clicked “yes” and it worked.

However, I noticed that my global username didn’t change.

I clicked “Update profile info” again and chose a community that has my new username and it didn’t update my username (or location info which I also updated)

Is this a bug?

Comment: Probably caching? It seems to have updated now.

Comment: that’s what I thought too.   I posted a workaround I discovered to copy a different profile below.

Answer (score 7):

OK, this is more of a workaround I discovered.

To change your “network profile” username, you must choose a **different** community profile than you chose the last time you clicked “Update profile info”.

I’m sure this is not intended behavior, but the workaround works fine for now.